# View to show specific columns dynamically

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-addin

I've custom list which has columns for each week of the year,

i.e. The columns are named after the weeks (i.e. the date listed below)

4/27/15

5/4/15

5/11/15

5/18/15

5/25/15

6/1/15

6/8/15

6/15/15

6/22/15

6/29/15

and so on for the entire year

I want to have a view, that will show only the columns for the current week and the 3 weeks out, i.e. if I pull the view now, it would show the columns with the following names:

4/27/15

5/4/15

5/11/15

5/18/15

Is there a way to programatically do this without setting up views manually?? The only way I can think of is very primitive, i.e. set up a monthly view and recreate it for each month....

Answer (score 0):

View fields are Static. Means you can't change it dynamically.

You can try couple of options

1. Create a view and include all fields. Now use jQuery/JavaScript/JSLink to dynamically hide unwanted fields.
2. Create a custom webpart - Use `GridView` control and select data source with dynamic fields. Here you will loose out of the box feature like Custom Actions etc.

Note - Also revisit your approach of having a field for each week. I think you can use a single field to capture date and use that to find week number. For example below formula will give you Week Number for date `StartDate` field

```
=IF(INT((StartDate-DATE(YEAR(StartDate);1;1)+(TEXT(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(StartDate);1;1)-1);"d")))/7)=0;52;INT((StartDate-DATE(YEAR(StartDate);1;1)+(TEXT(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(StartDate);1;1)-1);"d")))/7))
```

Comment: How would I do option 1?

Comment: I mean,  I am not sure where to use the jQuery/JavaScript/JSLink to calculate the current date and only show the 4 columns... and hide the other ones that are outside the date range. 

I can't revisit the approach as I need to store the data for each of those weeks so it needs a column.

Answer (score 0):

You can write some code to dinamically change the view using SPView, for instance:

```
SPList list = oWebsite.Lists["mylist"];
SPView view = list.Views["myview"];
view.ViewFields.Add("somefield"); 
if (view.ViewFields.Exists("otherfield")) view.ViewFields.Delete("otherfield");
view.ViewFields.MoveFieldTo("somefield", 6);
view.Update();
```